# How to factorize code properly?

Tags: c++, function, methods

I've a very basic programming question. Imagine I've two functions whose definition is practically the same except that they vary only in an internal binary condition. The rest of the code in both functions is practically the same.

In order to have a readable and easy-to-maintain code, I was wondering whether there's a better solution other than using a bool parameter that selects the operation mode of those functions? Is there any `design-pattern` for that?

In the code below, I'm illustrating my doubt with two functions named `doA()` and `doB()`. The dots (`....`) correspond to the code that is exactly the same to both functions.
I created a new `doNew()` function with an additional boolean parameter to chose the appropriate functionality. However, note that although this is a possible solution, it's still inefficient because of the duplicated code inside the body of both `if` conditions.

```
void doA( ..... ){
     .....
     .....
         if(x!=y){
             ....
             ....
             ....
         }
     .....
}

void doB( ..... ){
     .....
     .....
         if(x==y){
             ....
             ....
             ....
         }
     .....
}

void doNew( ....., bool selectionMode ){
     .....
     .....
         if(selectionMode == true){
             if(x==y){
                 ....
                 ....
                 ....
             }
         }
         else{
             if(x!=y){
                 ....
                 ....
                 ....
             }

         }
     .....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would also use a boolean parameter that will distinguisch between them. I would  not use a complicated pattern for a that simple procedure.

I would use

```
void doIt(..., BOOL is_equal) {
   ...
   if((a == b) == is_equal) { // or: is_equal ^ (a == b)
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

to ultimatively reduce redundance. I would also define independent names

```
void doA(...) {
    doIt(..., true);
}

void doB(...) {
    doIt(..., false);
}
```

because I consider flag parameters in the API to be bad.

Comment: It is a XOR, so if it is true, it inverts the result of `a == b`. So you dont even need do duplicate the body of the if-clause.

Comment: thanks! how common is it to use a XOR? since the code might be used for other people in the future, I would like that people might understand rapidly what's going on.

Comment: @Peter: If you think the XOR is not self-descriptive enough you can rename your `selectionMode` resp. @marc's `flag` to `bool should_be_equal` and then use `if ((a==b) == should_be_equal) {}`, which does essentially the same thing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: this is imho the best way, I updated the answer

Comment: @marc I assume the doIt() API should be a private method in case we're dealing with classes, right? so that we force that a given object can access only doA() or doB().

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I did understand your modified solution, however, I didn't get the idea of the `XOR`. The `doA()` function corresponds to the `is_equal` case, right? So, in the case of the `XOR` to be true, we would need that only one of the operands is true and the other false, right? however, for the doA(), we'll have something like: `true xor (a==b)` =>` true xor true = false`. Shouldn't we use the EQUIVALENCE logical operator or better said the negation of the XOR?

Comment: @Peter: yes, `a^b` is equivalent to `(~a)==b` and `a==(~b)` (and, in the case of booleans as we have here, also to `~(a==b)` and therefore `a!=b`). So exchanging `^` for `==` really just inverts the meaning of your boolean flag variable.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that being said, this means that the `doA()` function with `is_equal=true` is used when we want to validate the case `if(x==y)`, right? => `(~a)==b` and `a==(~b)` => `(~is_equal)==(x!=y)` and `(is_equal)==(x==y)` => `(~true)==(false)` and `(true)==(true)` => `true`. Is that correct? The `doB()` function will be then used for the other case (`x!=y`)

Answer (score 3):

I would say you make the `do` as a template function and a binary function as a functor parameter for the function. Something like:

```
template <class BinaryFunctor>
void do(...,BinaryFunctor f)
```

This binary functor would return a `bool` which you can use inside `do`.

Sample code for functor:

```
struct Equals
{
    Equals(int x , int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y){}
    bool operator()() const { return m_x == m_y;}

private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};
struct NotEquals
{
    NotEquals(int x , int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y){}
    bool operator()() const { return m_x != m_y;}

private:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
};
template<class BinaryFunctor>
void doSomething(BinaryFunctor f)
{
    if(f())
    {
        //Condition satisfied
    }
}
int main () 
{
    doSomething(Equals(10,11));
    doSomething(NotEquals(10,11));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you mind in giving an illustration of your proposed solution? I'm not really familiar with `functors` :S.

Comment: A functor is really just a class which overloads the `operator()`, so that it can be called like a function. Given an object `f`, which has an `operator()(int x, int y)`, you can call `f(x, y)`. Just as if `f` had been a function. But with the difference that you're actually invoking an operator on a class type, which might have additional state and so is a lot more flexible

Comment: @Naveen, thanks! I guess functors can also be templated, right? in case of the `==` or `!=` one could use it also with `bool`, `float`, etc. variable types, right?

Comment: @Peter: Yes, of course. Mine was just an example to show the synatx. In fact STL has many useful functors such as `std::equal_to<>` which can be used here.

Answer (score 3):

You can write this as:

```
if(selectionMode && x==y || !selectionMode && x!=y)
    //....
```

There also other ways of doing this. You can pass a functor(eg: a function pointer) which does the comparison. You can write a template with a functor template argument and define the two functions with the template.

Update:

People supplied a couple of examples so I will show you a different one, this one uses plain function pointers and does not pass the two values to compare but passes the result of the comparison. (note: the other examples are preferred but the more examples you see the better)

```
//type of the function pointer
typedef bool (*dofuncptr)(bool);

bool do_istrue(bool b) {
    return b;
}

//negates the input
bool do_isfalse(bool b) {
    return b;
}

void doX(dofuncptr fun) {
    //...
    if (fun(x == y)) {
        //....
    }
    //...
}

int main() {
    //you can use it like this:
    doX(&do_istrue);
}
```

Comment: thanks! do you mind in giving an example on how to apply the `functor` for this specific case? I'm not really familiar with `functors`.

Comment: thanks for the example! In which cases does your second solution could be prefered?

Comment: It's just an example to show you how can you use a function pointer. I wouldn't use it for this task, but, as you learn more stuff, might be useful later.

Answer (score 3):

A number of people have suggested using functors and that's good advice. The great thing for you is that functor equivalents of == and != and other such comparison operators already exist as part of the standard C++ library. Here is how I'd do it:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <class T, template <class T> class BinaryFunctor>
void doSomething(T x, T y, BinaryFunctor<T> f) {
  if (f(x, y)) {
    std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "False" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  doSomething(5, 5, std::equal_to<int>());
  return 0;
}
```

The `doSomething` template function takes two arguments of the same type `T` and a single argument of type `BinaryFunctor<T>`. Note that T appears in all three parameters and therefore must be the same in all the arguments that are passed. So passing two `int`s and an `std::equal_to<int>` is fine (as I have done in the example) because `T` can be instantiated to `int` and `BinaryFunctor` to `std::equal_to`.

`std::equal_to` is an example of one of the standard library's comparison function objects (or functors). It is simply a class that overrides `operator()` so that an object of type `std::equal_to` can be used as though it were a real function. So when an object of type `std::equal_to` is passed into the function as the `f` argument, you can use it like `f(someInt, anotherInt)`.

Now if you want to change the comparison operator to `!=` instead, you only have to change the function call to `doSomething(5, 5, std::not_equal_to<int>());` and it will work as expected. You'll also find other functors such as (omitting the `std` namespace): `greater`, `less`, `greater_equal`, `less_equal`, and others.

Comment: Could you please illustrate how the definition/declaration of such a method inside a class would be? In my case, I've a `templated` class whose definition is in a `.h` file and its declaration in a `.cpp` file (as in [parashift](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13))

Comment: I found the way! For template initialization it should be sth. like: `template void CFoo<double>::doSomething(double, double, std::equal_to<double>); `

Answer (score 1):

For a dynamic solution I would use pointer functions.

```
void(*doNew)(...);
doNew = &doA;
doNew(...);//now calls doA
doNew = &doB;
doNew(...);//now calls doB
```

For a static solution...
I would use a value type template function. 
Ex.

```
template<bool TMode>
void doNew( .....);
template<>
void doNew<TRUE>( .....);
{
     .....
     .....
             if(x==y){
                 ....
                 ....
                 ....
             }
     .....
     .....
}
template<>
void doNew<FALSE>( .....);
{
     .....
     .....
             if(x!=y){
                 ....
                 ....
                 ....
             }
     .....
     .....
}
```

Then you could use it like...

```
doNew<FALSE>(...); // is equivalant to doNew(..., false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a pattern, you need a refactoring technique.

What I tend to do is write four functions so that you get

```
DoA()
{
   Part1();
   SpecificForA();
   Part2();
};

DoB()
{
   Part1();
   SpecificForB();
   Part2();
};
```

You may need share some variables between them as parameters. It could be that these functions turn out to be useful, reusable functions. More likely, you find out that more refactoring is needed. This is now easier, because after extracting these functions, it is more clear to you what they do.